# What's the difference between the IMAP and sendemail?

Tags: imap

We often heard about `IMAP` and `sendemail`.

so what's the difference between them?

Comment: One is a specification of a protocol for fetching email, and one is a command for sending email?  I don't really understand your question because they're not even the same class of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In high-level terms, `sendmail` is an open-source mail *server* application. `IMAP`, or **I**nternet **M**essage **A**ccess **P**rotocol, is a *protocol* (i.e. a formal specification) for how email *clients* receive mail from a server (like `sendmail`, but there are many others). Specifically, IMAP servers keep email messages *on the server*, and the mail client downloads copies. The IMAP protocol defines how the client and server should keep them in sync.

Think of IMAP as a rulebook. `sendmail` and other email servers implement the server's set of rules, and email clients implement the client's set.

Comment: Is the IMAP as rulebook on server and client's two sides?

Comment: If you're curious, the IMAP protocol (i.e. "rulebook") is [RFC 3501](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501). It defines things like the [commands that can be sent by client applications](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6), [responses that can be sent by servers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-7), possible error states, data formats, etc. Every client application that supports IMAP has to implement some or all of the IMAP client specification. *How* the clients do that is up to the developers. Similarly, all IMAP-compatible servers have to implement the server specs.